# converting Instance type ArrayList to Instances object

Tags: java, arraylist, weka

I have implemented an `ArrayList` which it's type is `Instance`, and by writing some code, I have read the positive instances and negative instances from a file and according to their class lable, add them to the related `ArrayList`. Now I want to know how can I convert the type of this ArrayList to Instances type and then be able to use some methods and classes of `Weka API` in order to resample it and create a classifier?

below is a bit of my code.

```
public class MyDecision {
 double m=0.1;
 double d=0.1;
 private ArrayList<Instance> positiveInstances;
 private ArrayList<Instance> negativeInstances;
 Filter filter;

 private double[] classlabels;
 public MyDecision() throws Exception{

       positiveInstances = new ArrayList<Instance>();
       negativeInstances = new ArrayList<Instance>();

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\workspace\\MyDecision\\littleMyChurn\\Churn.arff"));
        ArffSaver saverTets = new ArffSaver();
        ArffSaver saverTraining = new ArffSaver();
        Instances trainData = new Instances(br);


     // Make the last attribute be the class
        trainData.setClassIndex(trainData.numAttributes() - 1);
        br.close();


            classlabels=trainData.attributeToDoubleArray(trainData.numAttributes()-1);

        for(int i=0;i<=trainData.numInstances()-1;i++){

            if(classlabels[i]==0){  
            positiveInstances.add(trainData.instance(i));
            }

            else if(classlabels[i]==1){             
            negativeInstances.add(trainData.instance(i));
                }
        }

        Resample resample = new Resample();
```

}
}

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your Arraylist so:

```
ArrayList<Instance> positiveInstances = new ArrayList<>();
```